# Mysql Query and PHP loop compare

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm developing many projects on php, and sometimes i need to output some statistics from mysql database. This task have two solution:

**First**: php loop is sending queries to mysql and get statistics:

```
$tables = array('user', 'news', 'tender');
$stat   = array();

foreach ($tables as $table)
{
    $stat[$table] = $db->execute(sprintf("SELECT count(*) FROM %s", $table));
}
```

**Summary for first solution**: i'm sending 3 queries

```
SELECT count(*) FROM user;
SELECT count(*) FROM news;
SELECT count(*) FROM tender;
```

**Second**: is mysql select

```
$tables = array('user', 'news', 'tender');
$SQL    = array();

foreach ($tables as $table)
{
    $SQL[] = sprintf('(SELECT count(*) FROM %1$s) as %1$s', $table);
}

$stat = $db->execute(sprintf("SELECT %s", implode(', ', $SQL)));
```

**Summary for second solution**: i'm sending 1 query

```
SELECT
    (SELECT count(*) FROM user) as user,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM news) as news,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM tender) as tender
```

**Both methods have returned the array:**

```
array(users => 11273891, news => 817623818, tenders => 12311);
```

Dear community, what do you think, **which method is better** for different types web applications?

Comment: Less queries == better

Comment: `SELECT 'users' as tableName, COUNT(*) as recordCount FROM users UNION SELECT 'news' as tableName, COUNT(*) as recordCount FROM news SELECT 'tender' as tableName, COUNT(*) as recordCount FROM tender`

Comment: I think so too, but I would like to understand why

Comment: i will send only one query

Comment: Why? Because sending a database query to be executed is an overhead, so the fewer queries made, the less that overhead is